# Hiding the Second Play/Pause button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a play/pause button for my slider. I have it working and it's perfect. Almost. The slight problem I have (for which I am sure there is a quick fix) is that I want to show only one play/pause image that would switch classes when clicked.

My images work but since I am creating the two classes for play and pause, I have two images showing up next to my slider that have the same function! How do I hide (get rid of) of the second image while preserving the functionality of the second? I cannot just remove the second `ul` class from my HTML since I'm assigning attributes to it, but I cannot figure out how to not make it show up. I've tried searching online but none of the solutions address my specific problem.

Here's the code:

```js
$('#autocontrols').on("click", '.bx-start', function() {
  alert("Starting!");
  main_slider.startAuto();
});

$('#autocontrols').on("click", '.bx-stop', function() {
  alert("Stoping!");
  main_slider.stopAuto();
});

$('#autocontrols ul').bind("click", function() {
  if ($(this).attr("class") == "bx-start")
    $(this).attr("class", "bx-stop");
  else
    $(this).attr("class", "bx-start");
});
```

```css
/*auto start button*/

ul.bx-start {
  background: image-url("pause.png") no-repeat 0 0;
  height: 50px;
}

/*auto stop button*/

ul.bx-stop {
  background: image-url("play.png") no-repeat 0 0;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='autocontrols'>
  <ul class="bx-start">
  </ul>
  <ul class="bx-stop">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/wakek/2/edit)**

*First of all*
`<ul>` tag is not meant to be used as a <kbd>***button***</kbd> but rather to contain `<li>` list elements
so you need is something like this:

```
<span class="control start"></span>
```

with the related [css](/questions/tagged/css):

```
/* auto buttons */
.control{
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
.start { background: url("play.png") no-repeat 0 0;}
.stop  { background: url("stop.png") no-repeat 0 0;}
```

than the [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) you need becomes pretty trivial:

```
$('.control').click(function(){

  // First toggle the class
  $(this).toggleClass('start stop');

  // now booleanize the current class
  var isPlay = $(this).hasClass('start');

  if(isPlay){
     // do something like: main_slider.startAuto();
  }else{
     // do something like: main_slider.stopAuto();
  }

});
```

The code above is that flexible that allows you to even start an autoplay on document load assigning a HTML like:

```
<span class="control stop"></span> <!-- autoplaying so we need a stop class -->
```

and all the above will work even for that specific case.

Comment: Thanks immensely! Last problem though: Using the above, the play/pause buttons are now appearing side-by-side. I want them to be such that they appear to be the same button! Right now, clicking on play makes it disappear but the pause button is always present on its right and never goes away.

Comment: So my initial problem still exists. The two buttons are still side-by-side. Only one of them disappears on clicking, and the other one is always present.

Comment: @user3694391 have you clicked on the `jsBin` link I provided with the example? I'm really trying to help here with useful suggestions. Don't use UL, don't use two elements. If you take a close look at what its written in the answer above you'll get the point. There's all the code you need and even more.

Comment: Thanks again! I was missing one tiny thing. It works now! 
Slight caveat: Using span instead of ul has misplaced my play/pause button. It is now not in line with the slider element I had.

Comment: It completely works now! (except for the autoplay part, which I'm trying to work out).

Answer (score 1):

This example will toggle the visibility of elements. Set the initial display property of `.bx-stop` to `none`.

CSS:

```
.bx-start   { background: url( "play.png" ) no-repeat 0 0; height: 50px; }
.bx-stop    { background: url( "pause.png" ) no-repeat 0 0; height: 50px; display: none; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id='autocontrols'>
    <ul class="control bx-start"></ul>
    <ul class="control bx-stop"></ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$( '#autocontrols .control' ).on("click", function() {                
    $( '.control' ).hide().not( this ).show();              
});

$( '#autocontrols .bx-start' ).on( "click", function() {
    console.log( "Starting!" );
    main_slider.startAuto();
});

$( '#autocontrols .bx-stop' ).on( "click", function(){
    console.log( "Stoping!" );
    main_slider.stopAuto();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it only works on the first click. After the first click, both elements disappear completely (leaving no way to control the slider!).

Comment: How can I make it so that it works for every click? 

The problem is that with this solution both images still appear when nothing is clicked. After the first click, one image disappears. After the second click, both disappear! :(

Comment: Replace your complete example with updated example above, there is no reason that this code does not work.